# Not sure how to debug this npm install error. This is a wordpress theme that comes with a built-in gulp/webpack task automation

Tags: theme-development, themes

So I downloaded and installed this theme that comes with a built-in gulp/webpack task automation. I went over to the project folder (wp-content/theme/themename) and just ran npm install but I got this.

[image]

not sure whats exactly keeping npm install from running successfully.

Comment: It probably has to do with the versions of tooling - I'd check the documentation or contact the author.

Comment: I'm reading the screenshot and i don't understand, where is the error message? I see the audit warning but I see no failures. Are you sure it's WordPress help you need and not JS help? Where did you get the theme?

Comment: @TomJNowell  I got it from here. https://them.es/starter-bootstrap/

Comment: @fjimenez are you sure it actually failed? I've re-read your screenshot and I see no failures, my guess is you have mistaken the audit warning for a failure/error. NPM did indeed run successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> not sure whats exactly keeping npm install from running successfully.

Nothing stopped it, `npm` ran successfully in your screenshot. The problem is that you saw the audit messages and thought it was an error/failure, which is not the case.

Fixing the audit messages is entirely optional at this point, and the issues auditing raises may not even apply to you. You should proceed to the next step, and report the audit messages to the authors.